# Format a height-binding with a % instead of default px with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have a viewmodel bound to my html:

```
function ViewModel(height, color, replies, hasMissingReplies) {
  this.height = height + "%"; 
}
```

Now my layout is correctly shown but I do also some calculations with the ViewModel where I sum up the height which results in a NaN (Not a number) because  the height is a string.

Only when I remove the %-char then I have a integer... but then it is interpreted from html as pixel so my layout is wrong.

Is there any helpful in knockout I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could tackle this, but probably the simplest is to do something like:

```
function ViewModel(height, color, replies, hasMissingReplies) {
    this.height = +height; 
    this.heightString = this.height + "%";
}
```

Just keep two copies!

If you want a more "knockoutty" solution, you could use `computed` observables:

```
function ViewModel(height, color, replies, hasMissingReplies) {
    var self = this;
    this.height = ko.observable(+height); 
    this.heightString = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.height() + "%";
    });
}
```

But, unless you need your `height` property to be an observable, I don't really see the point.

Comment: ok that works. But is there an approach in using the features of kockoutjs?

Comment: @HelloWorld: See my update, but I won't bother using `observable` and `computed` unless you actually need those features. See [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor).